# LaTeX Beamer, TikZ and overlays — page numbering issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, numbering, overlays

I'm using `\onslide<…->` for overlays in TikZ:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertpagenumber{}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw node[] at (0, 0) {$s_0$};

            \onslide<2->{
                \draw node[] at (1, 1) {$s_1$};
            }

            \onslide<3->{
                \draw node[] at (2, 2) {$s_2$};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

…and there are no more annoying additional bullets in the headline for every single overlay, but the page number is still increasing (so I'm getting only one bullet but 1, 2, 3 as page numbers). Is there any solution this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the pagenumbering problem by using `\insertframenumber{}` instead of `\insertpagenumber{}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber{}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw node[] at (0, 0) {$s_0$};

            \onslide<2->{
                \draw node[] at (1, 1) {$s_1$};
            }

            \onslide<3->{
                \draw node[] at (2, 2) {$s_2$};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```